# Django: How to searialize a formset

Tags: django

Django:

How can i serialize a formset so that i can send the data as JSON.

I know how to do for a single form using [django-remote-forms](https://github.com/WiserTogether/django-remote-forms). It converts the form to a dict and later I can dump as JSON.

Comment: Have you already POST the form and you are just trying to turn that request into JSON once received by the server? request.post should already be a python dictionary. You should be able to serialize that no problem.

Comment: I want to show the form first. So I want to pass the form with all the fields , help texts etc. Then later after i Post, if there are any errors i want to get all the errors along with form